# django - got stuck in path generation problem

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

The function:

```
def custom_path(path):
    new_path = os.path.abspath(path)
    def get_path():
        return new_path
    return get_path
```

The problem is in `custom_path` that when called inside this `get_image_path` function, it creates a directory with absolute path like `<function custom_path at 0x7f432d99e158>/somedir/finalName.*ext`, but I want it to return as a string representation. My code:

```
def get_image_path(instance, file):
    '''
    saves file to some location
    '''
    file_path   = custom_path*
    new_file    = random.randint(1, 45360789120)
    name, ext   = get_file_ext(file)
    ranstr      = random_string_generator(size=4)
    final_      = f'{ranstr}_{new_file}{ext}'
    return f'{file_path}/{new_file}/{final_}'
```

The sender:

```
from ... import custom_path, get_image_path

custom_path('posts')

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    image   = models.FileField(upload_to=get_image_path, null=True,
              blank=True, verbose_name='article image (optional)')
    ...
    ...
```

Otherwise, I have to modify this function as ...

```
def get_image_path(instance, file):
    ...
    ...
    return f'posts*/{new_file}/{final_}' # and so on for *different models..
```

I've also tried something like this...

```
def get_image_path(instance, file):
    ...
    ...
    return f'{new_file}/{final_}'

base = os.path.dirname('posts/')
upload_path = base + os.path.join(str(get_image_path))

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    image   = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path, null=True,
              blank=True, verbose_name='article image (optional)')
    ...
    ...
```

outputs: `''/newDir/newFile.*ext`, how to get rid from it? ️️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `custom_path` returns internal function `get_path`, so it works like this:

```
foo = custom_path()  # foo is a function
path = foo()  # path is str now
```

or, shorter code:

```
path = custom_path()()
```

Here is my test:

```
>>> import os
>>> def custom_path(path):
...   new_path = os.path.abspath(path)
...   def get_path():
...     return new_path
...   return get_path
... 
>>> foo = custom_path('test')
>>> foo
<function custom_path.<locals>.get_path at 0x7f7c123f8620>
>>> path = foo()
>>> path
'/home/pashawnn/test'
```

In your case you have to add braces in f-string:

```
return f'{file_path()}/{new_file}/{final_}'
```